# How to use solidity library with truffle

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-test, library, solidity-0.5.x

I'm using truffle `V5.1.13` and when I run `truffle test` the `res` variable contains a transaction receipt rather than the expected 2. I notice if I remove everything that has to do with the library things work as expected.

Why is this happening? How can I use my library?

Contract code:

```js
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

library TestLib{
    struct DataSet {
        uint a;
    }

    function assign(DataSet storage self) internal {
        self.a = 2;
    }

    function getA(DataSet storage self) internal view returns(uint) {
        return self.a;
    }
}

contract TestContract {
    using TestLib for TestLib.DataSet;
    TestLib.DataSet set;

    function getBalanceInEth() public returns(uint) {
        set.assign();
        return set.getA();
    }
}
```

Test code:

```js
    const TestContract = artifacts.require('TestContract')

    contract('TestContract', async accounts => {
        let TestContractInstance

        beforeEach('setup contract for each test', async function() {
           TestContractInstance = await TestContract.deployed()
        })

        it('Should return 2', async () => {
           let res = await TestContractInstance.getBalanceInEth()
           console.log(res)
           assert.equal(res, 2)
        })
    })
```

Migration Code:

```js
const TestContract = artifacts.require('TestContract')
const TestLib = artifacts.require('TestLib')
module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(TestLib)
  deployer.link(TestLib, TestContract)
  deployer.deploy(TestContract)
}
```

`console.log(res)` gives:

```
{
  tx: '0x1f05b5fa7ed635aaa619cc548a0a37ff9d9d57398d85ecb3f8000ed7e124373c',
  receipt: {
    transactionHash: '0x1f05b5fa7ed635aaa619cc548a0a37ff9d9d57398d85ecb3f8000ed7e124373c',
    transactionIndex: 0,
    blockHash: '0xe6bc488fce167970b781588d1c70c0b4a452834c78daf4f052c1a045575fd959',
    blockNumber: 3,
    from: '0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57',
    to: '0xf12b5dd4ead5f743c6baa640b0216200e89b60da',
    gasUsed: 42158,
    cumulativeGasUsed: 42158,
    contractAddress: null,
    logs: [],
    status: true,
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    rawLogs: []
  },
  logs: []
}
```

Comment: `await TestContractInstance.getBalanceInEth` returns a receipt because function `getBalanceInEth` is not declared `pure` or `view`.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, then you may be able to obtain the actual value by using `await TestContractInstance.getBalanceInEth.call()`

Comment: @goodvibration I can't use `view` because `getBalanceInEth` changes `TestLib.DataSet set`. Nevertheless i tried your suggestion and get the following during compile `TypeError: Function declared as view, but this expression (potentially) modifies the state and thus requires non-payable (the default) or payable.
        set.assign();
`

Comment: I didn't say that you should declare it `view`, I said that it returns a transaction receipt to your off-chain script because it is not declared `view`. It doesn't mean that you can declare it `view` without actually implementing it as one.

Comment: And BTW, what do you mean "I notice if I remove everything that has to do with the library things"? If you remove that, then the function does nothing! Please be more specific, and show exactly how you change the function.

Comment: @goodvibration ah you're right! With the library thing i just ment that if i removed the library and had `getBalanceInEth` simply return 2 the tests pass. I understand what i have to do now, thanks for pointing me in the right direction! :)

--edit
Oh and come to think of it when i removed the library i added ``view` to the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution to this problem is to change the contract code to the following:

```js
contract TestContract {
    using TestLib for TestLib.DataSet;
    TestLib.DataSet set;

    function setBalanceInEth() public {
        set.assign();
    }

    function getBalanceInEth() public view returns(uint) {
        return set.getA();
    }
}
```

And change the test code accordingly:

```js
const TestContract = artifacts.require('TestContract')

contract('TestContract', async (accounts) => {
  let TestContractInstance

  beforeEach('setup contract for each test', async function() {
    TestContractInstance = await TestContract.deployed()
  })

  it('Should return 2', async () => {
    await TestContractInstance.setBalanceInEth()
    let res = await TestContractInstance.getBalanceInEth()
    console.log(res)
    assert.equal(res, 2)
  })
})
```